# Google allauth with django

Tags: python, django, hosting, google-signin, django-allauth

when i do it in the local it work perfectly but when i host it's show this error :
NoReverseMatch at /login

Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:
Django Version:     4.2.3
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Note : in the local host it work and doesn't show this type of error

i try to edit the domaine in google cloud but the same error

Comment: do you have Google as social account provider registered in your hosted database as in the local database? Please post the error trace.

Comment: please provide more details like `settings.py`, `urls.py` and template.

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?